# fast data exchange between containers hosted in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, containers

I am working on moving a application which require near real time exchange of data between processes running in multiple containers in kubernetes cluster.
I am thinking of using redis cache for this purpose.

The type of data that needs to be exchanges are simple types like double,string values. The frequency of exchange needs to near real time(sub seconds)

are there any other more performant mechanisms available for exchanging data between containers hosted in kubernetes environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hugely complex question with way more nuance than can fit in here. It very much depends on the object sizes, uptime requirements, cluster scale, etc. I would recommend you try all of them, evaluate performance, and analyze failure modes as they apply to your use case.

Some things you can try out:

- Redis
- Memcached
- Local files with mmap
- Network block device with mmap
- NFS with mmap
- All three of the above with RocksDB
- Postgres
- Kafka

On the encodings side evaluate:

- JSON (don't use this, just for baseline)
- ProtocolBuffers
- CapnProto
- Msgpack
- Maybe BSON?